# Не отображаются полигоны при добавлении матрицы вида

Tags: c++, opengl

Не отображаются полигоны при добавлении матрицы вида. Квадрат находится в точке (0,0,0). Без матрицы вида он появляется в верхнем левом углу.
Есть шейдер:

```
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec4 vertex; // <vec2 position, vec2 texCoords>

out vec2 TexCoords;

uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 projection;

void main()
{
TexCoords = vec2 (vertex.z, 1.0f - vertex.w);
gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(vertex.xy, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

Матрицу создаю так:

```
glm::vec3 cameraPos = glm::vec3 (m_ViewXPos, m_ViewYPos, -30.0f);
glm::vec3 cameraFront = glm::vec3 (m_ViewXPos, m_ViewYPos, 30.0f);
glm::vec3 cameraUp = glm::vec3 (0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
m_ViewMatrix = glm::lookAt (cameraPos, cameraFront, cameraUp);
```

`m_ViewXPos` и `m_ViewYPos` равны `0.0f`

Вот что получается:

```
{-1.0,  0.0,  -0.0, 0.0},
{ 0.0,  1.0,  -0.0, 0.0},
{ 0.0, -0.0,  -1.0, 0.0},
{-0.0, -0.0, -30.0, 1.0}
```

Матрица проекции:

```
m_ProjectionMatrix = glm::ortho (0.0f, (GLfloat) m_ViewportSize.x, (GLfloat)m_ViewportSize.y, 0.0f, -100.0f, 100.0f);
```

Пробовал менять размеры матрицы проекции (ставил от -5000 до 5000) Ничего не появляется в этом диапазоне.

Что не так я делаю, чтобы отобразить с этой матрицей?

Comment: Попробуйте установить предпоследний параметр glm::ortho в 0.1f. Передаёте ли вы матрицу вида в шейдер? Попробуйте установить cameraPos.z в 30.0, а cameraFront.z в -30.0. Возможно мы просто видимо заднюю невидимую сторону квадрата.

Comment: Может быть из за того что направление камеры cameraFront смотрит по x и y в позицию камеры. Попробуйте указать координаты объекта в cameraFront.

Comment: Ребят, всем спасибо) 
Проблема оказалась в том, что я не использовал(glUseProgram) шейдер, а сразу передавал в него матрицу вида, поэтому ничего не показывалось)